# How to NOT suspend when using light-locker

Tags: linux, screensaver, display-manager

I have `light-locker` installed.
Running `light-locker&` creates a screensaver. Then I can run `light-locker-command -l` to lock the screen.

The problem is that when I lock screen with that command, screen goes blank and PC suspends. How to **only** lock screen, without any side effects like suspending?

I use LightDM as my DM, so I'd like to use it for locking as well.

I'm on Arch Linux, kernel 4.15.2.

Comment: Does the standard `Ctrl+Alt+L` suspend the PC? If so, the problem will be how the lock function is configured, rather than a specific problem with `light-locker-command -l`. You haven't stated your Linux version, but Ubuntu 17.10 seems to have problems in this area.

Comment: No, I don't even have `Ctrl+Alt+L` keybinding.